# How to make Imageview not overlap Textview in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have problem to make this widget not overlap each other, what i found like below

***(preview when imageview invisible)***
[image: invisible image]
**(preview when imageview visible)**
[image: visible image]
Here my xml snippet code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_news"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tak Ada Nomor Anrean, Masyarakat Sesalkan Pelayanan Kantor Pos Senpokdsoa"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_published"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4 Menit lalu"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_headline_img2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_news"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tak Ada Nomor Anrean, Masyarakat Sesalkan Pelayanan Kantor Pos Senpokdsoa"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_news"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_published"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4 Menit lalu"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title_news"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_news"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_news" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_headline_img2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note:** If you are using `ConstraintLayout` then try to manage every view by setting constraints of view. Here you used `LinereLayout` to display two `TextView` vertically which can be done by setting constraints like I did.

Comment: Thanks, so i in constraints layout i have to make all child inside setting constraints too, i just realize that

Comment: Yes, Main purpose of ConstraintLayout is that you can manage all your views in single Layout. No need to take multiple LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. You can upvote my answer so it will be helpful to other developers. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

In the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_01"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="The text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_01"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Create a constraint from the end of the textView to the start of the ImageView
    `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_01"`

If you want the text to remain left justified, set the bias to 0.0.

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
```

And the key is making sure setting the width to 0dp:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: agreed, 0dp width is the key, but I had a similar situation and it only works if I have the start/end (or left/right) constraint on both views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_news"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_headline_img2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_news"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Tak Ada Nomor Anrean, Masyarakat Sesalkan Pelayanan Kantor Pos Senpokdsoa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_news"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_published"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="4 Menit lalu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_news"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_news" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Implementation Given as follows, You can try

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Tak Ada Nomor Anrean, Masyarakat Sesalkan Pelayanan Kantor Pos Senpokdsoa"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4 Menit lalu"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sample_headline_img2" />
</LinearLayout>
```